# Unable to implement reverse scroll pagination using InfiniteScroll with package react-infinite-scroll-component

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

Hey guys I am trying to implement reverse scroll pagination using InfiniteScroll with package react-infinite-scroll-component but unable to do so. Normal scroll down pagination is working but reverse scroll is
not firing the method fetchMoreData2 which I have defined in my script even no error is also been shown. Please guide me.

```
    <div
          id="scrollableDiv2"
          style={{
            height: 300,
            overflow: 'auto',
            display: 'flex',
            flexDirection: 'column-reverse',
          }}
          >


          <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.listData.length} 
          next={this.fetchMoreData2}       

      
          scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv2"
          inverse={true}
          hasMore={true}
          style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }}
      

          >
        <ul>
          {this.getList()}
      </ul>
   </InfiniteScroll>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't get any guidance or way(I tried with their available properties) to implement reverse scroll pagination using that package so I achieved it in custom way without using that package.

```
**Putted this line in Constructor**:
 this.scrollRef = React.createRef();


**Putted the ref in the scrollable div inside render method**:
<div ref={this.scrollRef}>
//scrollable content
</div>

**Putted this line in componentDidMount method**:
this.scrollRef.current.addEventListener("scroll", this.scrollTrackFunc);


**Putted this line in componentDidUnMount method**:
this.scrollRef.current.removeEventListener("scroll", this.scrollTrackFunc);

**Added this method to track reverse scroll**:
scrollTrackFunc = () => {
      if (
        this.scrollRef!==null && this.scrollRef.current.scrollTop == 0
      ) {
   
        this.fetchData();
      }
    }
```